# How to get output of a sql with additional special characters

Tags: postgresql, psql

Long story...

I am trying to geenrate a crosstab query dynamically and run it as a psql script..

To achieve this, I want the last line of the sql to generated and appended to the top portion of the sql.

The last line of the sql is like this.... "as final_result(symbol character varying,"431" numeric,"432" numeric,"433" numeric);"

Of which, the "431", "432" etc are to be generated dynamically as these are the pivot columns and they change from time to time...

So I wrote a query to output the text as follows....

```
psql -c "select distinct '"'||runweek||'" numeric ,' from calendar where runweek between current_runweek()-2 and current_runweek() order by 1;" -U USER -d DBNAME > /tmp/gengen.lst
```

While the sql provides the output, when I run it as a script, because of the special characters (', "", ) it fails.

How should I get it working? My plan was then loop through the "lst" file and build the pivot string, and append that to the top portion of the sql and execute the script... (New to postgres, does not know , dynamic sql generation and execution etc.. but I am comfortable with UNIX scripting..)

If I could somehow get the output as
("431" numeric, "432" numeric....etc) in a single step, if there is a recommendation to achieve this, it will be greatly appreciated.....

Comment: If you run this from the shell (and quoting is your problem) you could use a here-document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using double quotes around the argument, double quotes inside the argument must be escaped with a backslash:

```
psql -c "select distinct '\"'||runweek||'\" numeric ,' from calendar where runweek between current_runweek()-2 and current_runweek() order by 1;"
```

Heredoc can also be used instead of `-c`. It accepts multi-line formatting so that makes the whole thing more readable.

```
(psql [arguments] <<EOF
  select distinct '"'||runweek||'" numeric ,'
     from calendar 
     where runweek between current_runweek()-2 and current_runweek()
   order by 1;
EOF
) > output
```

By using `quote_ident` which is specifically meant to produce a quoted identifier from a text value, you don't even need to add the double quotes. The query could be like:

```
select string_agg( quote_ident(runweek::text), ',' order by runweek)
 from calendar
 where runweek between current_runweek()-2 and current_runweek();
```

which also solves the problem that your original query has a stray ',' at the end, whereas this form does not.

Comment: Rewriting it like this select string_agg(quote_ident(runweek::text),' numeric,' order by runweek)
     from (select distinct runweek from calendar
     where runweek between current_runweek()-2 and current_runweek()
  ) a;   gives the output as ""432" numeric,"433" numeric,"434" which is not exactly what I want, but I used shell commands to append the missing "numeric" string to the code... while adding the string " numeric ," in the subquery results in the "" place for the entire string and not just the "433" or "432".... but at least I have a way to move forward.... Thanks...